# Opening an excel template for editing in VB.NET via Process.Start()

Tags: vb.net, excel

I need to open a .xlt for editing, like so:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Template.xlt", "Editable=True")
```

But I don't know the correct switch in Excel. This is the same as right-clicking on an .xlt and choosing "Open", whereas the default action is "New".

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Process.Start("Excel.exe", @"C:\Users\Master\Desktop\Book1.xltx");
```

(Looks like in VB you just omit the `@` and `;`.)